# How do I show bijectivity of this function?

Tags: functions, quotient-spaces

I have the following problem:

> On the intervall $[0,2\pi]$ endowed with the subspace topology one declare two points to be equivalent if they are equal ore one is zero and the other one is $2\pi$. Denote by $M$ the quotient space with the quotient topology and by $p:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow M$ the canonical projection. Consider the map $$f:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow S^1$$ We first need to show that there exists exaclty one $g:M\rightarrow S^1$ such that $f=g\circ p$. And then that $g$ is bijective.

I found $g([\Theta])=(cos(\Theta),sin(\Theta))$ But I don't think that this function is injective isn't it? Could you maybe help me or give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you think it's injective? Could you give an example of two distinct points which map to the same place?

Comment: If I take $[\Theta],[\Theta']$ such that $g([\Theta])=g([\Theta'])\Leftrightarrow (cos(\Theta),sin(\Theta))=(cos(\Theta'),sin(\Theta'))$ right? but cos and sin are not bijective on $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: Ok, but specifically which points could they fail to be bijective on?

Comment: sorry I don't understand this question, could you reformulate it

Comment: The only two elements of $[0,2\pi]$ which $\sin$ and $\cos$ simultaneously map to the same value are $0$ and $2\pi$. But does $[0]$ equal $[2 \pi]$?

Comment: hmm sorry, but $sin(0)\neq cos(0)$ so I quite don't get it

Comment: Sorry, no I mean $\sin 0 = \sin2\pi$ etc.

Comment: But there are more values for example $sin(0)=sin(\pi/2)$ ect. or do you mean values that satisfy this equation from above